# ICommand no funcionando

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xaml

Tengo un botón que utiliza un `icommand` para llamar la operación a realizar, pero este no realiza nada al compilar.

Archivo `xml`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="appTurismoIqq.Vistas.DetalleEntidadPage"
         BindingContext="{Binding Main,Source={StaticResource localizador}}">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout BindingContext="{Binding detalleEntidad}" Padding="5">


<Button Text="Ver Mapa" FontSize="Small" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HorizontalOptions="Center" Command="{Binding MapaCommand}"></Button>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Modelo:

```
    public ICommand MapaCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(IrMapa);
        }
    }

    private async void IrMapa()
    {



        //   VistaPrincipal.GetInstancia().DetalleSucursales = new DetalleSucursalVModelo(this);
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MapAppPage2(latitud2, longitud2, calle1));

    }
```

No sé que error podría estar cometiendo, lo que se me ocurre es que el modelo donde estoy colocando el `icommand` no sea el mismo de la vista pero lo he revisado y si coincide.

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en IrMapa nunca ingresa al presionar el boton? Validaste si el `localizador` devuelve una instancia correcta del `ViewModel` que tiene este command ?

Comment: El BindingContext que se puede leer, parece que esté desde un Locator que tengas registrado en la aplicación. Puedes comprobar en el evento BindingContextChanged que el BindingContext no sea nulo, para evitar que ese sea el error.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
  public ICommand MapaCommand => new Command(async () => await IrMapa());
```